# Dados +upload de Images duplicando no nodejs!

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou começando agora com o NodeJS, e estou testando um exemplo que que salva dados junto com um upload de images.

Está funcionando, mas a imagem fica duplicada.

Queria saber onde está o erro, e o porque disso:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');


app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(multer({dest:'tmp'}).single('file'));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

app.post('/process_post', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.file.originalname);
    console.log(req.file.path);
    console.log(req.file.mimetype);
    console.log('-----------');
    console.log(req.file);


   var file = __dirname + "/tmp/" + req.file.filename + '.jpg';

   fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
      fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
         if( err ){
            console.log( err );
            }else{
               response = {
                  message:'Arquivo enviado com sucesso!',
                  filename:req.file.filename + '.jpg',
                  first_name:req.body.first_name,
                  last_name:req.body.last_name
               };
            }
         console.log( response );
         res.end(JSON.stringify( response ));
      });
   });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Servidor iniciado em http://localhost:%s", port)

})
```

**HTML:**

```
  <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_post" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     First Name: <input type = "text" name = "first_name">  <br>
     Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "last_name"> <br>
     Foto: <input type="file" name="file" size="50" /> <br>
     <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
  </form>
```

**CONSOLE.LOG**

```
C_OURO.png
tmp\19ac6310c0d101cb280f1f9bbfe1bfb0
image/png
-----------
{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'C_OURO.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'tmp',
  filename: '19ac6310c0d101cb280f1f9bbfe1bfb0',
  path: 'tmp\\19ac6310c0d101cb280f1f9bbfe1bfb0',
  size: 5555562 }
{ message: 'Arquivo enviado com sucesso!',
  filename: '19ac6310c0d101cb280f1f9bbfe1bfb0.jpg',
  first_name: 'Nome',
  last_name: 'Sobrenome' }
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Podes acrescentar o código do cliente que efectua o upload ?

Comment: @IvanVilanculo incluido!

Comment: Não sou um guru em node  js mas me diga, quantas vezes o log `console.log(req.file.originalname);` aparece na sua consola?

Comment: Aparece apenas uma vez. Vou incluir o log.

Comment: Ok agradecia! Mas vou tentar replicar isso na minha máquina logo que chegar a casa!

Comment: Descobri o erro:  app.use(multer({dest:'/tmp/'}).single('file'));

Faltou a barra /tmp/ antes e depois, mas queria saber o porque! =/